# NSTextView will resize but parent NSScrollView not Resizing with setFrameSize

Tags: text, resize, nstextview, nsscrollview

First let me say I'm coming from the iOS world and am trying to make my first OSX app. So apologies for the question if the answer is obvious. :)

I'm trying to setup an NSTextView to resize according to the amount of text in it. I've been successful at getting the NSTextView to resize properly but it's superview (NSScrollView) won't resize.

This is what I have so far...

```
[self.messageBodyTextView setVerticallyResizable:YES];

[self.messageBodyTextView.layoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer:self.messageBodyTextView.textContainer];
[self.messageBodyTextView.layoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self.messageBodyTextView.layoutManager numberOfGlyphs]) inTextContainer:self.messageBodyTextView.textContainer];

NSRect rect = [self.messageBodyTextView.layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:self.messageBodyTextView.textContainer];

[self.messageBodyTextView.textContainer setContainerSize:rect.size];

[self.messageBodyTextView setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(self.messageBodyTextView.bounds.size.width, rect.size.height)];

[self.messageBodyTextView.textContainer setHeightTracksTextView:YES];

[self.messageBodyScrollView.documentView setFrameSize:rect.size];
[self.messageBodyScrollView.documentView setFrame:rect];
[self.messageBodyScrollView setFrameSize:rect.size];
```

self.messageBodyTextView resizes just fine with all this code (I have a feeling a have a bunch of redundant code in there). But self.messageBodyScrollView either doesn't resize at all or if I try to use setBounds then it not only resizes messageBodyTextView to messageBodyScrollView's full size but it also stretches out the text inside.

note: messageBodyTextView and messageBodyScrollView are both attached to my IB doc as IBOutlets.

My code used to be a lot shorter but this is where I've gotten to by adding in anything I can find to make these two views match up.

Any help would be very much appreciated!